# Can `Fix` and `(,)` be seen as functors in some sense?

Tags: haskell, composition, functor, category-theory

I've been wondering what a *complete, all-encompassing* context for `instance Functor (f :.: g)` would be. The immediate thought that pops into my head is:

```hs
newtype (f :.: g) a = Comp (f (g a))
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :.: g) where
    fmap f (Comp x) = Comp (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

But then, two contravariant functors would also compose to be covariant, like so:

```hs
instance (Contravariant f, Contravariant g) => Functor (f :.: g) where
    fmap f (Comp x) = Comp (contramap (contramap f) x)
```

Already not a promising beginning. However, I've also noticed that technically, `f` and `g` don't even have to have kind `* -> *` -- the only requirement for `f :.: g :: * -> *` is that `f :: k -> *` and `g :: * -> k` for some `k`. This means that non-functor types could compose to be functors, e.g.

```hs
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
instance Functor (Fix :.: (,)) where
    fmap f (Comp x) = Comp (go x) where
        go (Fix (x,xs)) = Fix (f x,go xs)
```

`Fix :.: (,)` is isomorphic to the `Stream` type:

```hs
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
```

so this does seem to be a non-trivial issue. This got me thinking -- if Haskell's `Functor` typeclass represents categorical functors from Hask to Hask, does that mean types like `Fix` and `(,)` could be functors working on some other categories? What would those categories be?

Comment: `(,)` is a function, and a function is a functor.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what would the domain and codomain of `(,)` be, so that you could write a function `fmap :: dom a b -> cod ((,) a) ((,) b)`?

Comment: Have you seen [`FunctorOf`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eoo16m/base_category_polymorphic_functor_and_functorof/)? `FunctorOf (~>) (->) Fix` is a valid functor instance and I believe it is possible to define functor composition in the way you want. However to get proper compsition we need instances of [unsaturated type-level functions](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/242). The functor instance of tuples would be `FunctorOf (->) (~>) (,)` i.e. `Bifunctor (,)`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack Aha, I had not seen that and it looks very useful. I do notice the `hoistCofree` function has a `Functor` constraint -- does this mean the instance can't be created?

Comment: `hoistCofree` just witnesses that `Cofree` is a functor, it is the `fmap` for `FunctorOf (~>) (~>) Cofree` or equivalently `BifunctorOf (~>) (->) (->) Cofree`. See Edward Kmett's [*hask*](https://github.com/ekmett/hask/) or the more self-contained [gist](https://gist.github.com/ekmett/b26363fc0f38777a637d).

Comment: The point of `FunctorOf` is that we *don't* need a name for "what should we call the class of functors like `Fix`". We expose a singular interface that captures all functors. Libraries can independently define `instance FunctorOf (~>) (->) Fix` and use `FunctorOf (~>) (->) f => ..` and it works together without coordinating or waiting on a third-party library that defines `class FFunctor hof where hof :: (f ~> f') -> (hof f -> hof f')` or what-ever. Same with `Functor`, `Bifunctor`, .. why stop there? What if I need `Trifunctor` or `Quadfunctor`? Better to have one all-encompassing interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and we can read off exactly what sense that is from the shape of the constructor. Let's look at `(,)` first.

## The `(,)` Functor

```
(,) :: * -> * -> *
```

This takes two types and produces a type. Up to isomorphism, this is equivalent to

```
(,) :: (*, *) -> *
```

i.e. we might as well uncurry the function and take both arguments at once. So `(,)` can be viewed as a functor for `Hask × Hask` to `Hask`, where `Hask × Hask` is the [*product category*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category). We have a word for a functor whose domain is the product of two categories. We call it a [bifunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Bifunctors_and_multifunctors), and it's [actually in `base` Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor). Specifically, a bifunctor `p` is capable of turning maps from `(a, b)` to `(a', b')` in the product category into maps from `p a b` to `p a' b'`. Haskell's typeclass writes this in a slightly different but equivalent way

```
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

Having a map `a -> b` and a map `c -> d` is exactly equivalent to having a map `(a, c) -> (b, d)` *in the product category*. (What I mean by that is: the maps `(a, c) -> (b, d)` in the product category are *defined* to be products of maps `a -> b` and `c -> d`).

## The `Fix` Functor

We can deal with `Fix` the same way.

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

Its shape is

```
Fix :: (* -> *) -> *
```

It takes a one-argument type constructor and produces a type.

Now, in Haskell, the `* -> *` part can be *any* one-argument type constructor, but categorically it's *much* nicer to work with functors. So I'm going to make the slightly stronger constraint (which it turns out we'll need in a minute) that the `* -> *` argument to `Fix` is a `Functor`, i.e. a functor from `Hask` to `Hask`.

In that case, `Fix` has the right shape to be a functor from the [functor category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category) `Hask ^ Hask` to the category `Hask`. A functor, categorically, takes objects to objects and arrows to arrows. So let's take that one step at a time.

The object part is easy, we've already defined it. Specifically, `Fix` takes the functor `f` (functors are the *objects* of a functor category; read that again if it doesn't make sense yet) and maps it to the type `Fix f` that we just defined.

Now, the *arrows* of a functor category are [natural transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation). Given two functors `f, g :: C -> D`, a natural transformation `α` from `f` to `g` is a mapping from the *objects* of `C` to the *arrows* of `D`. Specifically, for every object `x` in the category `C`, `α x` should be an arrow in `D` going from `f x` to `g x`, with the following coherence condition:

> For every arrow `h : x -> y` in `C`, we must have `(g h) . (α x) === (α y) . (f h)`

(Using notation such as function composition *very* loosely, in true category theory spirit)

Drawn as a commutative diagram, the following must commute,

[image: A commutative diagram representing (g h) . (α x) === (α y) . (f h)]

Haskell doesn't really have a built-in type for natural transformations. With [Rank-N types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types), we can write the correct shape

```
(forall a. f a -> g a)
```

This is the shape of a natural transformation, but of course we haven't verified the coherence property. So we'll just have to trust that it satisfies that property.

With all of this abstract nonsense in mind, if `Fix` is going to be a functor from `Hask ^ Hask` to `Hask`, it should take a natural transformation to an ordinary Haskell function, and it should have the following shape.

```
fixmap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Fix f -> Fix g
```

Once we have this type, we can write the implementation fairly easily.

```
fixmap h (Fix inner) = Fix (h . fmap (fixmap h) $ inner)
```

or, equivalently (by the rules of natural transformations),

```
fixmap h (Fix inner) = Fix (fmap (fixmap h) . h $ inner)
```

I'm not aware of an idiomatic name for this shape of functor, nor am I aware of a typeclass that encompasses it, but of course nothing stops you from making it yourself.

Comment: As an aside: The naturality condition is automatically satisfied in Haskell due to parametricity. It's one of the "theorems for free."